# Can I throw exception again when I catch it?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

```
try{
      WebElement naimi_logo = firefox.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href=\"/astana/\"]/img") ) ;

      naimi_logo.click();


  }catch( IllegalStateException e){
      throw new IllegalStateException("this image is not clickable!") ;
  }
  catch(NoSuchElementException e){
      throw new NoSuchElementException("logo is not found!!") ;
  }
```

Should I really throw exception in my catch block? Or is it better to just print what happened to console?

Does the order of the catches matter?

Comment: That depends on your requirements, but sure, this is possible. But the catch block is not really meant to just re-throw an exception, rather to handle it, or to throw your own customized type of exception.

Comment: If the information from the first exception doesn't have enough information to handle it then yes you should rethrow with the necessary info.  Since its not in english or spanish I dont know if this is one of those cases.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this catch blocks?

Comment: As for the order of the catch: if the two exceptions are not related to each other, no. But it should be clear, when you have:
catch{Exception e){ handleA(); }
catch(NullPointerException npe){ handleB(); }

this WILL cause compile time issues.

Comment: @defaultlocale, i m trying to test a website if it has a link(1) and link is clickable

Comment: @ERJAN I mean what stops you from using original exceptions (without catching)?

Comment: ERJAN: the catch blocks don't change anything here. Actually, you are making it a bit worse: you add an error message describing what the problem is, without first validating whether or not that is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your intent is to add more information when an exception occurs. In that case what you are doing is fine. However you will lose complete stack trace for the underlying exception.

You can use:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException.RuntimeException(String, Throwable)
```

If you don't want to lose the stack trace of original exception.

Comment: Make sure to avoid: log exception and throw new one its bad practice. Always just wrap it OR take care of it never combine.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I throw exception again when I catch it?

To just rethrow the exception you do

```
throw e;
```

On the other hand this is equivalent of not catching the exception at all and let it propagate.

Perhaps you want to give the exception a better message, but keep the exception class. You would then typically do:

```
}catch( IllegalStateException e){
    throw new IllegalStateException("this image is not clickable!", e);
}
catch(NoSuchElementException e){
    throw new NoSuchElementException("logo is not found!!", e);
}
```

> Should I really throw exception in my catch block?

This depends on what *your* method is intended to do. Your options are basically

- Catch and handle the exception gracefully. Your method can complete normally even in case of an "internal" exception.
- Catch the exception and wrap it in another exception more suitable for your level of abstraction.
- Let the exception propagate.